# Android: spinners & setOnItemSelectedListener & getSharedPreferencesString

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

1) In my activity I have a two spinners: **countrySpinner**, **citySpinner**. Second spinner is dependent on the first one - if user selects item A from countrySpinner, the values in second citySpinner will be updated as well, e.g. if user selects Russia from the first one, in the scond spinner he will get Russian cities...

<- it WORKS.

2) In my activity I have a button which saves the information which user provided in the spinners. Information is stored in shared app preferences. I didn't include this in the code example as it's not relevant.

<- it WORKS

3.In onCreate method of the activity I read previously saved values -> checkIfLocalSettingExists()) and assign values which were saved to 'countryStr' & 'cityStr' variables.

<- it WORKS

4.Then I would like to update spinner which have default values at the beginning. I have string which were stored in shared preferences, so to get proper element I'm using getIndex function, which returns me id of an element which should be set.

<- IT WORKS

5.After I got elements which need to be set on both spinner I can just set them. I'm assigning retrieved ids to spinners, however, setOnItemSelectedListener is executed twice don't know why and probably it's the reason that it doesn't work!.

<- IT DOES NOT WORK!

Code:

```
public class Settings extends ActionBarActivity{
public Spinner countrySpinner;
public Spinner citySpinner;
public String cityStr;
public String countryStr;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_settings);
    countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.kraje_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Countries, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.przejscie_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.CitiesRussia, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);


    if (checkIfLocalSettingExists())
    {           
        System.out.println("Gathered following values from settings");
        System.out.println("Country: " + countryStr);
        System.out.println("City: " + cityStr);
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.println("Setting the spinners...");
        System.out.println("Country spinner:");
        // I found the ID of saved country, I can set it in countrySpinner
        countrySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(countrySpinner, countryStr));
        System.out.println("City spinner:");

        //without this it didn't work at all, don't know why            
        if (kraj.toLowerCase().equals("russia"))
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.CitiesRussia, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        else if (kraj.toLowerCase().equals("ukraine"))
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.CitiesUkraine, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        else {
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.CitiesBelarus, R.layout.spinner_layout);
        }
        citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);

        // I found the ID of saved city, I can set it in citySpinner
        citySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(citySpinner, cityStr));       
    }   


    countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {               
            if (position == 0) {
                System.out.println("SELECTED RUSSIA");
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Settings.this,
                        R.array.CitiesRussia, R.layout.spinner_layout);                    
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
                citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }
            //
            else if (position == 1) {
                System.out.println("SELECTED UKRAINE");
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Settings.this,
                        R.array.CitiesUkraine, R.layout.spinner_layout);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
                citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("SELECTED BELARUS");
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Settings.this,
                        R.array.CitiesRussia, R.layout.spinner_layout);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
                citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }              
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
   }
private int getIndex(Spinner spin, String myString){
    int index = 0;
    String tmp = "";
    System.out.println("Im in get index function!");
    System.out.println("Seraching for: " + myString);
    for (int i=0;i<spin.getCount();i++){
        tmp = spin.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        System.out.println("checking if " + tmp.toLowerCase() + " equals " + myString.toLowerCase());
        if (tmp.toLowerCase().equals(myString.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println("FOUND IT --> " +tmp + " ---->" + i +", its: " + myString);
            index = i;
            break;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND IT --> " +tmp + "-->" + i +", its NOT: " + myString);

    }
    return index;
}
```

Code output:

```
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Gathered following values from settings
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Country: Belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: City: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: ----
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Setting the spinners...
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Country spinner:
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Im in get index function!
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Seraching for: Belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: checking if russia equals belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> russia -->0, its NOT: Belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: checking if ukraine equals belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> ukraine-->1, its NOT: Belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: checking if belarus equals belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: FOUND IT --> Belarus ---->2, its: Belarus
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: City spinner:
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Im in get index function!
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: Seraching for: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: checking if cityA equals terespol
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> cityA -->0, its NOT: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: checking if cityB equals terespol
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> cityB -->1, its NOT: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.590  I/System.out: checking if cityC equals terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> cityC -->2, its NOT: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: checking if cityD equals terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> cityD -->3, its NOT: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: checking if cityE equals terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: NOT FOUND IT --> cityE -->4, its NOT: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: checking if terespol equals terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: FOUND IT --> Terespol ---->5, its: Terespol
03-16 15:51:12.594  I/System.out: 5
03-16 15:51:12.642  I/System.out: SELECTED BELARUS
```

So the Code for Belarus is 2, its correctly returned by getIndex function, then spinner is set to the valid value (BELARUS). 
Return code for Terespol is 5, it's correctly returned by getIndex function, then spinner is not set correctly due to the fact that setOnItemSelectedListener is executed for countrySpinner.. again (check last line from the output). Why? I set the listener only for countrySpinner, not for citySpinner?! In consequence citySpinner is set not to 5th element but 1st. Why in the world it doesn't work!?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you select any item from the spinner manually or by calling `setSelection()` like this-

```
countrySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(countrySpinner, countryStr));
```

It will definitely call `onItemSelected()` And in `onItemSelected()` you are loading your city spinner values which resets your selection although you made a particular item selected before.

To resolve this issue, you have to keep track of whether you've loaded your country spinner values from your `checkIfLocalSettingExists()` and in that case you don't have to set the city spinner adapter in `onItemSelected()` because you are already doing that.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Good idea, but how can I do that?

Comment: You can create a boolean flag and before calling setSelection() set it to true. Check that flag in onItemSelected(). If that flag is true then set adapter for city spinner else don't do that.

Comment: You wrote that: "you are loading your city spinner values which resets your selection although you made a particular item selected before. "  Yes, that's right. Firstly I'm reading countrySpinner values and assign them to this spinner, then citySpinner values are updated as well. Later I check the values stored for citySpinner and I'm trying to assign the value as well. The thing which I do not understand is the fact that listener is set only for countrySpinner not for citySpinner! Why countrySpinner.onItemSelected() is executed if I change value for citySpinner in line:

Comment: countrySpinner.onItemSelected() is executed because you call setSelection() on country spinner . It is not because of city spinner.

Comment: Firstly I set countrySpinner:
countrySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(countrySpinner, countryStr)) <- here countrySpinner is updated + default values from adapter are loaded into the cityspinner,
Then I set values for citySpinner:
citySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(citySpinner, cityStr));     
Why listener is being executed if listener is set only for countrySpinner?! -->  countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() ?

Comment: sorry but I can't get it work, if one function works -> changing values in the countrySpinner in the realtime, the other one -> reading values onCreate function is not. Completely don't understand it. I used print line function at the end of my class with some dummy text, there is no other line being executed later. However, after printing my line the countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener is executed in the end, and value is printed afterwards as well!! So it looks like:
 "DUMMY TEXT"; "RUSSIA"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by setting additional listener in which i set allowModification flag to true. Still don't know why previously it didn't work and why listener is always executed in the end (bug?)

```
 citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            allowModification = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```